# how can get an object instead of array like FETCH_OBJECT instead of FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, pdo

I have a class names Product.php in my model directory. in my view directory, I have an index.php currently I fetching data out of my table using this function

the code works fine but I want to field $row['name'] to be called as an object. because I am not sure the way I'm doing is a semantically correct for oop programming.

```
 public function display(){

 $pizza = $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM pizza");



   while ($row = $pizza->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  


      $data[]= $row;

   }   return $data;  

  }//end of method
```

and in my index page i write :

```
$blog = new Product();
$name = $blog->display();


foreach ($name as $row ) {

    echo $row['name']. '<br>'; 

}
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

Then for your index.php:

```
$blog = new Product();
$name = $blog->display();


foreach ($name as $row ) {

    echo $row->name . '<br>'; 

}
```

Here is a really good article to read for PDO.

[PDO Tutotrial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: thank you for an answer but instead of $data[]= $row; what I should write also in index.php  instead of echo $row['name'] what I need to write.